# What compiler to download, how to download the compiler, and how to add the compiler to Qt? (ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, compiler-construction

I've tried downloading the MinGW compiler from here: http://www.mingw.org/category/wiki/download . In that folder there was a file called "x86-mingw32-build.sh". I tried setting the path Build & Run ->  Compiler to the path that that file is located in, but that didn't work. I also tried setting it to "/home/user/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64/bin/qmake", which didn't work either. I'm at a total loss. If anyone who knows something about this could help me I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you trying to cross compile for Windows?

Comment: You need to execute the file in bash - `sh -c "/path/to/file.sh"`

Comment: Did you try  `sudo apt-get install mingw32` or any of the other mignw32 packages?

Comment: Yeah, you probably want to use a package for your distro, if there is one, instead.

Comment: Is there even a MinGW for linux? That in itself seems contradictory.

Comment: i don't get what the downvote is about - questions about common dev tools/software are valid here.

Comment: Yes, there is a mingw32 compiler in the Ubuntu repositories.  You can use it to build Windows applications on Linux (cross-compiling).  If you have a mingw build of Qt, you can build Qt applications under Linux for Windows.  You can even build a Windows installer using NSIS under Linux!  Agree with @sepp2k, not sure if the original poster is asking for a cross compiler.

Comment: Sorry guys, I talked with a friend and he told me I needed G++/gcc so I used this command in the terminal: "sudo apt-get install gcc g++". It's currently installing.

Comment: Remember on linux you would usually (probably almost always) install packages from your package manager instead of going to some web page looking for some type of installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, so the issue is that you are trying to work with a cross-compiler for Windows, whereas - based on your comment -, it seems you simply want to build software on Linux for Linux, i.e. no cross compiling.

In that case, you will need a compiler like gcc or llvm/clang. Both should be available from your repository and could install them as follow:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install clang
```